# Git (github) specify binary file behavior

Tags: git, github, merge

I have some binary files e.g. pdf in my git project and would like to specify the behavior for that file.
Is it possible to ignore the file when pulling and always overwrite githubs copy with the local copy when pushing.

For example: I have a latex project and like to have pdf preview on git. I want git to just ignore conflicts in the pdf file and just push up the pdf. (Not interested in latex builder hooks, this is just a example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PDF is a binary files , you can simply use the LFS project:

### ***[`Git LFS`](https://git-lfs.github.com/)***

> An open source Git extension for versioning large files
>
> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: Does this store the files on github so that the files can be opened in the git browser page?

Comment: Yes it does, you can also store it anywhere else you like as well